# Use Monolog in my namespace

Tags: php, monolog

I want to integrate Monolog logger (https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) to my own framework
I have followed the PSR0 standard for structuring my framework so that namespacing is easy an follows the directory structure

Now, I would like the logging to reside under Core/Logger directory, but Monolog uses its own namespace and I am wondering if I need to go and change its namespaces to match my structure?
I believe that I do not need to do that, but I think I am missing something.

Is there a way to use it by just putting it under my Core/Logger dir and not change its own namespace?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no you can't put it in there without changing the namespace if you want to follow PSR-0.

The longer answer is that you should really use [composer](http://getcomposer.org) to pull in the monolog files and then they'll happily live in the vendor/ directory and be autoloadable and you should not have to care where they reside on the filesystem.

Comment: Answer directly from the source :). Thanks